# Renaming files in folder and subfolders using a list- Bash Script/Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to rename files contained within folders & sub folders. I've many sub folders under each folder which contains various files, so my aim is to run a script at top level folder which hopefully will scan through entire array of sub folders and rename the old file names to new file names given in a separate text file.

For example:

Abc075.tif----------Xyz.tif

def958.pdf----------pqr.pdf

I've this bash script that works on folder level that is if I copy this into each folder (and sub folder) and then run from there.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r old new
do
    arr=( ${old} )
    if (( ${#arr[@]} == 1 ))
    then
        mv "${arr[0]}" "$new"
    else
        echo "Error: Multiple files found for $old: ${arr[@]}"
    fi    
done < replace.txt
```

Sorry my knowledge is limited but I've tried to modify this to;

```
#!/bin/bash
find -type f -iname '*.*' -print0 | while read -r old new
do
    arr=( ${old} )
    if (( ${#arr[@]} == 1 ))
    then
        mv "${arr[0]}" "$new"
    else
        echo "Error: Multiple files found for $old: ${arr[@]}"
    fi    
done < replace.txt
```

This would execute but won't work. I've also tried the first script by using this find command;

```
find /path -type f -name "*.*" -exec /path_of_script.sh {} +
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you have old name and new name so why not just moving them directly rather than considering array or find command?

Comment: Can you give an example of what's in the `replace.txt` file and some examples of where you'd find the files in what directories?

Comment: @almasshaikh Yes I've old file names and new file names given in replace.txt but I want the script the go in each sub directory check for file name and replace with the new one, hence using find (like I mentioned above my skills are limited in this field so if you think I'm over complicating the problem then please point me in right direction).

Comment: using `-print0` means null-terminated output from `find`. I think you need to specify a complementary IFS for your `while read`, but I'm not sure how you would do that. Good luck.

Comment: @zerodiff replace.txt has old file name separated by a tab and then new file one same line followed by new line character and so on. I don't have directory location given in replace.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a batch `mv` command you'll need to create a tab separated file that'll add explicitly the directory structure that your replace.txt misses, like so:

```
full/path/old.stuff<TAB>full/path/new.stuff
```

In order to achieve this you'll have to:

1. list the files with their paths
2. extract the basename (but keep a link to the path info)
3. match the basenames with your replace.txt file to get the new names
4. recreate the new full paths
5. and then do the `mv` command.

**So we'll need a few steps using a big table and tools like `find`, `basename` and `join` (the latter also requires some sorting)**

1) Go to the uppermost directory where the changes have to be made and simply start with:

```
find . > all_paths.ls
```

Then we get basenames similar to what you have in your replace.txt:

```
for path in `cat all_paths.ls` ; do basename $path ; done > all_names.ls
```

We'll also need the dirnames:

```
for path in `cat all_paths.ls` ; do dirname $path ; done > all_dirs.ls
```

2) These two will make a useful table (combines the names to match your replace.txt file while still keeping track of the dirs):

```
paste all_names.ls all_dirs.ls > all_name-dir.tsv
```

3) NOW we make use of your replace.txt file thanks to the magic of `join`:

```
sort replace.txt > replace.sorted.txt
sort all_name-dir.tsv > all_name-dir.sorted.tsv
# join will work fine because "old basenames" are in the first column of both tables
join -t "<TAB>" all_name-dir.sorted.tsv replace.sorted.txt > todo_name-dir-newname.tsv
```

`<TAB>` stands here for the real tab character (you can enter it in shell with CTRL+V then TAB key)

The result should have three columns with content like:

```
old.stuff<TAB>full/path/<TAB>new.stuff
```

4) To be able to use all this with the move command, we'll just need to reshape this slightly and glue the paths back together (put some "/" back)

```
# get the columns back
cut -f2 < todo_name-dir-newname.tsv > todo_dirs.ls
cut -f1 < todo_name-dir-newname.tsv > todo_oldnames.ls
cut -f3 < todo_name-dir-newname.tsv > todo_newnames.ls

# glue 2 and 1 together for reconstructed old paths
paste todo_dirs.ls todo_oldnames.ls | tr "\t" "/" > todo_oldpaths.ls

# same for the new ones
paste todo_dirs.ls todo_newnames.ls | tr "\t" "/" > todo_newpaths.ls

# and we get the table we wanted
paste todo_oldpaths.ls todo_newpaths.ls > replace_table.tsv
```

5) Now finally you can proceed with moving:

```
for line in `cat replace_table.tsv`
 do oldpath=`echo $line | cut -f1`
    newpath=`echo $line | cut -f2`
    mv $oldpath $newpath
 done
```

Comment: FYI Here I used (a lot of) transitional files so each step is more easy to redo... Their extensions are `.ls` for simple lists and `.tsv` for tab separated values. Obviously all of them are also `txt` files by nature.

Comment: edited to clarify the 5 steps and correct the forgotten -t argument for join

Comment: thanks very much for such detailed answer. I've left for home now and will give it a go tomorrow morning. I shall post back the results. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: Again thanks for this. I used this and it works partially. I couldn't get step 5 to work however I used my bash script by replacing `replace.txt` with `replace_table.tsv` and it worked like a charm. you've saved me some serious amount of time. Most importantly now I know where the mistake was. There is a lot of new information to absorb here as I would normally do step 1-4 in windows. Thanks very much for that. I will now up-vote your answer as the best.